# Is MSVC strictly necessary to compile on windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, compiler-construction, cross-compiling

Some open source projects explicitly state that in order to compile on windows, they need a microsoft compiler (often a specific version as well, as latter versions are incompatible or will refuse to compile older code).

Since it seems absurd to me that, since there *are* foss compilers that can compile for windows, a microsoft compiler would be necessary for *any* fundamental task, I'm assuming this is because those projects use api calls to libraries (such as msvcrt*.dll) that, for some reason, mingw-gcc, clang and other ports of compilers for windows are unable to compile against.

My understanding of these requirements is shallow, since my experience with compiled code comes primarily from linux and this worries me, since getting a microsoft compiler is non-trivial. the only way to get them is through the express editions of microsoft's visual c++, and even then, the most recent version will completely refuse to install on an old winxp machine like mine and the only version available at the moment is vc++express2010, which requires registrations to turn from trialware into freeware (and even then i'm not clear on if that'll work or what it entails - perhaps OS hooks to "debug" and other intereference?).

1) My question is, do these projects depend on microsoft compilers due to building against these microsoft-only libraries (which apparently foss compilers can't do)?

It would seem absurd if the reason is the build script or preprocessor directives, since those can be relatively easily ported.

2) Also, is it possible that, even if I avoid any msvcrt/.net/etc. calls, i can still find myself needing a microsoft compiler to compile native windows software (assuming no usage of libraries that do perform those calls)?

3) Can I simply use clang and some widget library to make native windows software just as well?

4) Can I modify the source of a project so that it doesn't depend on a microsoft compiler?

(ok that's 4 questions, sorry, this is quite hard for me to express clearly).

Comment: which projects are you referring to? Clang (i.e. LLVM) doesn't have a working linker yet (AFAIK) so either you do the linking yourself or for now you stick with the MSVC's one

Comment: For one issue, compilers don't include the DLLs in with an executable, like a static library.  The programs interface with a DLL during run-time.

Comment: @MarcoA. an example of such a project is [clang/llvm](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#buildWindows). Doing the linking myself is not a problem, my concern is whether there is anything *impossible* to do without using msvc. Here's what I was reading before asking this question [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Building_XULRunner_with_Python#_Development_Machine_Setup_)

Comment: Most UNIX/Linux compilers produce object code in the same format.  Likewise, the format for libraries (both static and dynamic) is fairly well standardized.  Windows compilers, including those from Intel and Borland/Embarcadero, produce object code in a different format (at one point I believe COFF was an option but it's not the default).  The library file formats are even more different.  And consequently the set of compiler/linker switches is different.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i know that, but i'd assume that isn't an issue for any compiler, yet some specifically seem to want msvc to use these libraries.

Comment: Another sticking point is (or again used to be) the Windows SDK; those headers and libraries were only available from Microsoft or their licensees.

Comment: @David that would mean that it is due to the developer choosing to interface with libraries on windows that use that different format and the compilers/linkers not being equipped to deal with those formats, even those built for mingw.

Comment: @IvyLynx That was kind of my point ... except it's not necessarily a choice.  If a library is supplied only in the PC/DOS/Windows format then you don't have the option of using e.g. mingw.  Likewise if a library is only available in .a  or .so format I don't believe you'd be able to use that with an MS compiler.

Comment: @IvyLynx Also I don't believe the MS toolset includes a "make" utility.  (Borland C++ did, and included an option to generate makefiles, but the "native" project file format was proprietary.)

Comment: @David I don't intend to sound like a smartass, but I don't see how this can happen easily with software that is designed to be cross-platform. Another example would be, opengl vs directx - obviously linux has better support for the former and windows for the latter and you'd have to make changes to accomodate either depending on the platform, but that wouldn't necessarily bind you to a compiler (it can, just not necessarily) and in the end, you can just use sdl (for this example), since you've *planned* for cross-platforming. Hence why I call it a choice even though it might not always be one

Comment: @David a lack of make is somewhat secondary though isn't it? (again sorry if my tone sounds too direct :P). another 'make' can be used, such as 'cmake' or a python script and just interface to the appropriate compiler. At least, this is how I've understood things so far.

Comment: There's no one reason; each project is different.  That said, in my experience the most common reason (in the case of foss projects) is simply that Windows support is low priority for the developers, and they just haven't bothered to support more than one Windows compiler.  (In many cases adding support for another compiler would not be particularly difficult, if you wanted to.)

Comment: @IvyLynx It depends on what you mean by "cross-platform".  For example, Linux/UNIX software distributed in source form often includes a `configure` script to generate a makefile.  But such scripts assume (in my experience) that you have GNU make and some variant of `gcc`.  So in this case "cross-platform" means you can almost certainly build on any flavor of Linux and probably most variants of UNIX.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) My question is, do these projects depend on microsoft compilers due
>   to building against these microsoft-only libraries (which apparently
>   foss compilers can't do)?

Compiler vendors and GUI framework vendors can supply DLLs that perform similar to the MS DLLs. Some of the MS DLLs are *system* DLLs and are used by the other compiler and framework vendors.

If you are using compiler or framework specific DLLs, they need to accompany the installation of your programs (projects).

> 2) Also, is it possible that, even if I avoid any msvcrt/.net/etc.
>   calls, i can still find myself needing a microsoft compiler to compile
>   native windows software (assuming no usage of libraries that do
>   perform those calls)?

No.  If you scan through the posts on StackOverflow, there are many people who are using the Windows API directly, I guess what you are calling *native* windows software.   Usually, the code for these API are located in a system API.  The compiler translates the function call to a call into these DLLs, loading them as necessary.

> 3) Can I simply use clang and some widget library to make native
>   windows software just as well?

No, you can't.  That's why they exist.
Again, many people are using frameworks like Qt and xWidgets without the MS compilers.  I did that for a while.  I switched over to Visual Studio, primarily for the debugger.  I didn't like how other IDEs tried to use GDB.  Otherwise, I wouldn't use MS because they tend to go by the Microsoft Standard language rather than the ISO.

> 4) Can I modify the source of a project so that it doesn't depend on a
>   microsoft compiler?

No, that is why there are freeware and other compilers out there.
Hmmm, one can use Java to create GUIs that don't use the MS compiler, but they use the Windows API.

Try installing Cygwin.  When you look at all the libraries you will realize that projects can be created that don't use the MS Compiler.  Again, read through the StackOverflow posts and you will find that people are using other compilers, such as Intel, GNU, Clang, Greenhills and others.  Some compilers for embedded systems will also compile for Windows OS, so you can write code that works on both platforms.

Looks like you need to search the web for "GNU GUI tutorial C++" and see what pops up.  Also, search for "wxWidgets" and "Qt" for other frameworks.

Comment: Thanks, this answer covers most of what I couldn't understand clearly. However, I think my questions where more convoluted that I originally thought :P I'm not concerned so much about whether i'm using native windows calls, but more about whether there's a chance I can't do something without msvc - which, from your answer, seems like there isn't such a problem. I am aware of cygwin/mingw and the widget frameworks and how they bind on a source code level - if they don't explicitly need msvc, i'm fine with any of them.